# gulp-if javascript file but not in specific directory for gulp-useref

Tags: javascript, gulp

I would like to run minifaction on javascript files that are not in the ./src/components directory. I tried this:

```
    gulp.task('index', function () {
    var assets = useref.assets();

    return gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(gulpif('!./src/components/** && *.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

but it does not seem to be working (i.e. it preforms minification on js files in ./src/components anyway).

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

*Update facing the real problem*

Okay, that is a point. `gulp-if` uses [`gulp-match`](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-match) to evaluate conditions. There you can use an array of globs:

```
.pipe(gulpif(['*.js', '!./src/components/**'], uglify())
```

Still for others:

`gulp-if` might be the wrong approach. I'd suggest a stream queue.

```
var queue = require('streamqueue')

...

return queue.queue(
    // all the JS files without components
    gulp.src(['**/*.js', '!./src/components/**/'])
        .pipe(uglify()),
    // all JS files in components
    gulp.src('./src/components/**/*.js')
)
.done()
.pipe(doSomething())
```

This way you can do separate tasks on all your non-components, and afterwards execute common processes.

Code's not tested, but you get the idea looking at the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamqueue).

Comment: yes the problem is I am using gulp-useref. I will edit the original post with the full task

Comment: Fair enough. Updated the answer

Comment: I was thinking of using globs but doesn't the globs condition result in a true if any of them are true? If so, then it would result in true for all javascript files regardless of the path

Comment: Usually, yes. But exclusions work a little differently. First you tell them: All javascripts, but then: exclude everything from components. And that selection also runs down the paths you get from useref first.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here I believe is that `var assets = useref.assets();` stores the concatenated files in `assets`. Therefore, the paths of the individual files are lost and any gulp-if statement that uses the paths, useless.

There is an option for `useref.assets(noconcat: true)`. I thought I could then use:

```
var assets = useref.assets(noconcat: true);

return gulp.src('src/index.html')
.pipe(assets)
.pipe(gulpif(['*.js', '!./src/components/**'], uglify())
.pipe...
```

but this didn't work either. I am not sure why (perhaps the full paths of the files are not stored?).

Regardless the solution I eventually went with was to use gulp-usemin. gulp-usemin can do eveything I am trying to accomplish in my original post like so:

```
gulp.task('usemin', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.index)
        .pipe(usemin({
            js1: [uglify(), 'concat'],
            js2: ['concat'],
            css: [minifyCss(), 'concat']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

where js1 and js2 are pipeline ids (specified in the html).

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that `useref.assets()` stores the concatenated files in assets. But, there is now an option to pass the non-concatenated files down the stream. Not sure if this will fix the problem or not, but in the other example that was posted earlier, the options are not being passed in correctly. Options should be passed in as an object, so it should look like this:

```
var assets = useref.assets({ noconcat: true });

return gulp.src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(assets)
    .pipe(gulpif(['*.js', '!./src/components/**'], uglify())
    .pipe...
```

I will update the docs for that because I just noticed there is no example with the options in it.